# concatenation between variable and string

Tags: matlab

I am trying to concatenate a variable with a string. For example I want to get d1, d2 and d3.

I know that to concatenate 'd' with 1 , 'd' with 2 and 'd' with 3 , it is necessary to convert  1, 2 and 3 to string. The code below work very well :

```
['d' num2str(1)] = 4;
['d' num2str(2)] = 5;
['d' num2str(3)] = 6;
```

But when I tried the code below:

```
for i=1:3
['d' num2str(i)] = i+3;
end
```

Unfortunately I always get the error : **An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot contain LEX_TS_STRING**

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: This is **very strongly** discouraged by everyone, including [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html). It's much better to use `d(1)`, `d(2)` etc. Of course, if you're writing this to a file and **have** to have it on this format, I guess you can't avoid it. However, I would still recommend keeping it on the format `d(ii)` in MATLAB, and use `evalc()` when you're writing it to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [EVALC](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) -

```
for i=1:3
    evalc(['d' num2str(i) '=' num2str(i+3)]);
end
```

**EDIT 1:** If d1=3; and you need to get d2 = d1+4 and d3 = d2+4;, use this -

```
d1 = 3;
for i=2:3
    evalc(['d' num2str(i) '=d' num2str(i-1) '+4']);
end
```

Comment: And if I have for example d1=3; and I want to get d2 = d1+4 and d3 = d2+4; how to edit your code. Please can you add this to your code above ? thanks in advance

Comment: I get Undefined function or variable 'd2' and 'd3' :)